# Vim makeprg and errorformat for Go

Tags: vim, go

I would like to be able to build and run Go code from within vim with access to quickfix window if there are compilation errors.

To achieve something close to this with Java I added the following to my .vimrc:

```
autocmd Filetype java set makeprg=ant\ -find\ build.xml
autocmd Filetype java set efm=%A\ %#[javac]\ %f:%l:\ %m,%-Z\ %#[javac]\ %p^,%-C%.%#
```

I have the following currently for Go in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd Filetype go set makeprg=go\ run
```

What can I have to make `:make` (or `:make %`) act like it would for a good 'ol C program with pretty error reporting and output below the buffer?

Comment: What you need is a compiler file for `ant`... there has to be one out there already. Did you try Google? There are also guides for using vim as an IDE for Java; the configuration should be the same, except you're using the golang syntax.

Comment: As far as I know ant is only for Java, not Go (which is unrelated to Java, doesn't use the JVM, etc.). I was just using Java as an example of what I'd done for a different language.

Comment: Once I tried to make a `errorformat` line for NAnt... and gave up. It's too arcane and difficult to test iteratively, like much of vim's script facilities. I love vim, but there are some things that are frustrating, especially because I know it _can_ be done. It's just too difficult and not enough examples of newer, non-Unixy stuff out there.

Answer (score 4):

For cases where your current working directory consists of a single program or library, the following works fine with Vim:

```
autocmd Filetype go set makeprg=go\ build
```

For cases where there is just one file you want to compile, I override this with:

```
:set makeprg=go\ build\ hello.go
```

More can be found at jnwhiteh's [vim-golang](https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang).

Comment: Oh and also what I do is just have a separate command that calls `:make %` then opens the quickfix window with `:copen`, usually mapped to a key like F7. (`map <silent> <F7> :make %<CR>:copen<CR>`).